# Conditionally asynchronously execute mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

How can I conditionally execute mocha tests based if the condition is an asynchronous function call?

I have tried to make an asynchronous implementation based on a [synchronous example](/a/42586302/303598). In both snippets below I expected `some test` to be executed since the promise returned by `asyncCondition()` is resolved to `true`.

First, I tried to `await` the condition:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const asyncCondition = async () => Promise.resolve(true);

describe('conditional async test', async () => {
  const condition = await asyncCondition();

  (condition ? it : it.skip)('some test', () => {
    assert.ok(true);
  });    
});
```

Result: `No tests were found`.

Next, I tried an asynchronous `before` hook:

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('conditional async test', async () => {
  let condition;

  before(async () => {
    condition = await asyncCondition();
  });

  (condition ? it : it.skip)('some test', () => {
    assert.ok(true);
  });
});
```

Result: `Pending test 'some test'`.

---

The code works if if the line `const condition = await asyncCondition()` is changed to execute a synchronous function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mocha run cycle](https://mochajs.org/#run-cycle-overview) runs all `describe` callbacks and collects the tests *synchronously*, so only synchronously available conditions can be used to toggle between `it` and `it.skip` during the `describe` callback execution.

> How can I conditionally execute mocha tests based if the condition is an asynchronous function call?

[Mocha provides `.skip()`](https://mochajs.org/#inclusive-tests) to...

> ...tell Mocha to simply ignore these suite(s) and test case(s).

`.skip()` can be used within a `before` to skip **all** tests in a test suite:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const asyncCondition = async () => Promise.resolve(false);

describe('conditional async test', function () {

  before(async function () {
    const condition = await asyncCondition();
    if (!condition) {
      this.skip();  // <= skips entire describe
    }
  });

  it('some test', function () {
    assert.ok(true);
  });

});
```

...or it can be used within a single test to skip just that test:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const asyncCondition = async () => Promise.resolve(false);

describe('conditional async test', function () {

  let condition;
  before(async function () {
    condition = await asyncCondition();
  });

  it('some test', function () {
    if (!condition) this.skip();  // <= skips just this test
    assert.ok(true);
  });

});
```